# MUI Checkbox defaultChecked - A component is changing the default checked state of an uncontrolled SwitchBase after being initialized

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a filter component that reads filters values from the search params. I want to set just the `defaultChecked` state of the checkboxes on mount.

Component looks like this:

```ts
import "./styles.css";
import {
  Checkbox,
  FormControlLabel,
  Box,
  FormGroup,
  Button,
} from "@mui/material";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const filterValues = [
  {
    value: 1,
    label: "One",
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    label: "Two",
  },
] as const;

export default function Filters() {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const onFilterChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    checked: boolean
  ) => {
    let filters = searchParams.get("filters")?.split(",") || [];

    const filter = event.target.value;

    if (checked) filters.push(filter);
    else filters = filters.filter((_filter) => filter !== _filter);

    if (filters.length === 0) searchParams.delete("filters");
    else searchParams.set("filters", filters.join(","));
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <FormGroup>
        {filterValues.map(({ label, value }) => (
          <FormControlLabel
            key={label}
            control={
              <Checkbox
                defaultChecked={searchParams
                  .get("filters")
                  ?.split(",")
                  .includes(value.toString())}
                onChange={onFilterChange}
              />
            }
            value={value}
            label={label}
          />
        ))}
      </FormGroup>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setSearchParams(searchParams)}>
        Set Filters
      </Button>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

The problem is, when I set the new search params after setting up the filters I get the following error:

```
 MUI: A component is changing the default checked state of an uncontrolled SwitchBase after being initialized.
```

Codesandbox example:

[image: Edit search-params-mui-default-checked]

The possible solution I see is to save initial checked states using `useState`, which would read all filters from the url, like this:

```
  const [checkedStates] = useState(
    filterValues.map(({ value }) => ({
      checked: searchParams.get('filters')?.split(',').includes(value.toString()),
    })),
  );
```

and setting the `defaultChecked` from it:

```
<Checkbox defaultChecked={checkedStates[index].checked}/>
```

It feels like unnecessary state duplication to me. Is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: default value must do not change after initialized
instead of default value, use value
Furthermore, do not pass the value of checkbox from the array out of react tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the SearchParams in your `onFilterChange` callback will cause the `useSearchParams` to reset its state, thus rerendering your component. This will rerender your MUI Checkboxes and set a different value as the `defaultChecked` value.

I believe using the `checked` prop instead of the `defaultChecked` prop would solve the issue. Unfortunately i cannot edit your sandbox to test it myself.

As you are just manipulating the searchParams yourself while staying on the same page, i think using a dedicated state (which changes on each checkbox click), would fit better, as you dont have to "apply" the filter anymore. I dont really know your usecase

Hope this helps somehow,
Mika

Comment: Hello, I do not want to use the `checked` prop, because what I want to do is set just the `default` checked state based on the search params. The 'searchParams' should change only after the `set filters` button click. This is why I provided the codesandbox to show the use case. Setting `searchParams` in the `onFIlterChange` callback does not reset the state. It is reset only after the `setSearchParams` call, which is done in the button's `onClick` handler.

Comment: I want to have more filters and only set new search params with the button click, after all filters are set properly. The button is setting new search params to fire a new http request. I want to avoid unnecessary request on each filter check.

Comment: @user9314872 the `defaultChecked` state is supposed to be defined once and never change. MUI creates the React Component, and then mounting it with the defaultChecked prop. If it changes to a different value in any rerender, MUI throws the encountered error. This is because the presence of the defaultChecked prop tells the MUI component to be `uncontrolled`. But in your case it should be controlled by the `searchParams`. A `controlled` component receives its state from a parent. An `uncontrolled` one manages itself. See [this](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-checkbox/#controlled)

Comment: Okay. I think I got it. I will add a new answer with my solution, so if you could take a look I would greatly appreaciate it.

Comment: Ill take a look. Can you maybe describe the use case? You got a filter with multiple checkboxes (at least for now). The checkboxes will be mounted with the values they get from the searchParams. What should happen when you click the button? Will it fire a request and set the searchParams accordingly? So, are the searchParams used for some kind state storage, or just to transfer state via e.g. a link?

Comment: The desired behaviour is like this:

- Set initial checkbox values from the search params
- Let the users select all filters they want without firing new requests
- After the users have all filters set, they can `set filters` with the button
- After the button is clicked, the search params are updated
- This changes the url, which fires the HTTP request for new data with the new filters

Comment: Ah okay. I cannot post comments because my reputation is too low lol. I have to answer it here. The new approach looks good, but i would rather use the `event.target.label`  as the id rather than the `event.target.value`, because you already have it in your filter configuration and its a bit more descriptive

Comment: I think I'll stick to `event.target.value`, because that's what I need on the backend and `labels` are only for the UI. Thank you for your responses. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on the @MGreif answers I understand that I need to make the checkboxes controlled components and use the `checked` prop instead a `defaultChecked`. So what I've done is:

I created a new state to read the filter values from search params:

```ts
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState(searchParams.get('filters')?.split(',') || []);
```

Then in the checkbox `onChange` handler I modify the state:

```ts
  const onFilterChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, checked: boolean) => {
    const filter = event.target.value;
    if (checked) setFilters((prev) => [...prev, filter]);
    else setFilters((prev) => prev.filter((_filter) => filter !== _filter));
  };
```

And then if all filters are set correctly, and the `Set Filters` button is clicked I call the `setSearchParams` to navigate to the new url and fire new HTTP request:

```ts
  const setFilters = () => {
    if (filters.length === 0) searchParams.delete('filters');
    else searchParams.set('filters', filters.join(','));
    setSearchParams(searchParams);
  };
```